# input with 2 classes, javascript affecting border color of one

Tags: javascript, html, css

The title may be confusing but what I want is simple ( I hope ).

I have an input that has 2 classes, one uses some piece of javascript that changes the border color of the input.
I dont want this to happen because some of my inputs have only 1 class and so they have different border color from the rest.

Can I edit the css of the other class ( not using javascript ) so that it maintains its original border color no matter how many classes I add to the input?

Comment: Please post your code or a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using !important on the class you want to keep.

```
.c1 {
    border-color: inherit !important;
}
```

See jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/a58Gc/.
For demo behaviour, remove the `!important` and re-run the fiddle.